# Filter a large text file using ID in another text file

Tags: text, filtering

I have a two text file, one file is composed of about 60,000 rows and 14 columns and another has one column containing the subset of one of the columns (first column) in the first file. I would like to filter the File 1 based on ID name in the file 2. I tried some command on net but none of them were not useful. It's a few lines of two text file (I'm on linux system)

File 1:

```
Contig100       orange1.1g013919m       75.31   81      12      2       244     14      2       78      4e-29     117   1126    435
Contig1000      orange1.1g045442m       65.50   400     130     2       631     1809    2       400     1e-156    466   2299    425
Contig10005     orange1.1g003445m       83.86   824     110     2       3222    808     1       820     0.0      1322   3583    820
Contig10006     orange1.1g047384m       81.82   22      4       0       396     331     250     271     7e-05   41.6    396     412
```

File 2:

```
Contig1
Contig1000
Contig10005
Contig10017
```

Please let me know your great suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Linux/Mac, you can do it on the command line (the `$` symbolized the command prompt, don't type it).

First, we create a `file2-patterns` from your `file2` by appending `.*` to each line:

```
$ while read line; do echo "$line .*"; done < file2 > file2-patterns
```

And have a look at that file:

```
$ cat file2-patterns 
Contig1 .*
Contig1000 .*
Contig10005 .*
Contig10017 .*
```

Now we can use these patterns to filter out lines from `file1`.

```
$ grep -f file2-patterns file1
Contig1000      orange1.1g045442m       65.50   400     130     2       631     1809    2       400     1e-156    466   2299    425
Contig10005     orange1.1g003445m       83.86   824     110     2       3222    808     1       820     0.0      1322   3583    820
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry, I'm very new in this field. Would you please kindly tell me how I should execute your solution?

Comment: Now, I get your solution. But, I have a large file 2, could you please let me know the right command for adding .* to each line of file 2?

Comment: So sorry for my stupid comments. I didn't notice the first lines of your answer for creating pattern from file file 2. Please accept my deep apologize and Thank you very much for your help. I try it.

Comment: I'm trying your solution on a server with 256G RAM. It finished after running  for 40 minutes without creating any error or output. What's wrong in your professional view?

Comment: I'd first try it on the smaller files you posted above, so you notice what's going wrong quickly... (it worked for me though) btw, are you familiar with the command line and the `>` operators?

Comment: I almost familiar with it, but not professional. the > operator use to write the output of the command to a new file. Actually, I used your command as    grep -f file2-patterns file1 > file1_1.txt, that the output (file1_1) was empty.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned in my previous comment, I used the command as yours, but the output file was empty.

Comment: but it works for the two small files you posted, right? if so, either there's something different with the large files, or you're not doing the same thing :) (maybe there are tabs or other whitespace characters in there... then appending `$line\s.*` instead of `$line .*` would work... (it uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html))

Comment: That's right. I tried it for small files posted here, it worked well. Yes, the files are tab-delimited. I created the pattern from file2 with $line\s.* and now I'm trying the grep command.

Comment: Dear friend, your command worked well for large files, too. Thanks a lot, I accepted it. but the time to finish the job is really long for filtering (47 minutes). Just out of curiosity, how the problem was solved with $line\s.* instead of $line .* ?

Comment: Well, how large is the file? Running grep should not take much longer than copying the file... The lines in the file are [regex patterns](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), so `Contig1 .*` matches `Contig1` followed by a space followed by zero or more characters (`.*`). By replacing the space with `\s` it matches not only on a space but also other whitespace characters, like a tab.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanation. The file isn't large, it's just 3.5 Mb, so it's unusual why the job takes long time, is it?

Comment: Yeah, maybe your harddisk is really slow or some other job is using all CPU (check with `top`). You can probably also speed things up with `^$line\s` instead of `$line\s.*` (only matching stuff from the beginning `^` and not bothering reading the rest of the line)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with python:

```
with open('filter.txt', 'r') as f:
    mask = f.read()

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        l = f.readline()
        if not l:
            break
        if l.split(' ')[0] in mask:
            print(l[:-1])
```